# Why introduce the $p$-adic numbers?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, big-list, schemes, p-adic-number-theory, big-picture

My current intuition about the p-adic numbers comes from the following three facts:

1. You can describe $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ with the $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ groups.
2. Hensel's lemma
3. We find that the p-adic integers are formal neighborhoods of closed points in $\mathbb{Z}$, so they naturally show up in the deformation theory of arithmetic objects (Schemes over $\mathbb{Z}$)

What are other reasons to consider p-adic integers/numbers?

Comment: Because they're fun.

Comment: When making the rationals and reals from the integers, it's customary to allow the numerical expansion to run indefinitely long to the right, and only finitely long to the left. The $p$-adics are what happens if you do it the other way, just for the heck of it. Turns out that if you do it that way, what base you're in actually matters. I find that a spectacular fact!

Comment: @GTonyJacobs You should unpack the entertainment for the audience!

Comment: Ostrowski's theorem tells us that every nontrivial absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent either to the usual one or to one of the $p$-adic absolute values.

Comment: It is natural to consider the natural injective map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ and to say that $\mathbb{Z}_p[p^{-1}]$ is a field. Then it is a matter of understanding this new field. It becomes the prototypal example of a completion of a field by a non-archimedean absolute value.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs To paraphrase Feynman, p-adics make arithmetic deformation theory possible, but that's not why we study them. :)

Comment: @Neal can you shine some more light?

Comment: @reuns, which $\Bbb Z_p$ you are meaning here? Is it $p$-adic integer or ordinary integer set?

Answer (score 11):

On one hand, the $p$-adic numbers are extremely natural objects of study: by [Ostrowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem) every nontrivial absolute value on $\mathbf Q$ is equivalent to either the usual absolute value or the $p$-adic absolute value for some $p$. So the $p$-adic numbers, together with the real numbers, give all the posible completions of $\mathbf Q$.

On the other hand, the $p$-adic numbers are also extremely useful, even if you only care about $\mathbf Q$. A great example of this is the [Hasse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle), that says (for example) that a homogeneous quadratic equation has a nontrivial solution over $\mathbf Q$ if and only if it does over $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf Q_p$ for each $p$, and the latter question turns out to be straightforward to answer.

Comment: So are p-adic numbers just the first example of where we see the local to global principle?

Answer (score 5):

About 40 years ago, a fellow who was doing C-star Algebras was teasing me about how none of my Number Theory would ever find applications in "the real world". I told him to just wait and see – some day, there would be crucial applications of $p$-adic numbers in Physics. I was kidding, but apparently there is a serious pursuit of $p$-adic quantum mechanics. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_quantum_mechanics).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Mahler%E2%80%93Lech_theorem), "the Skolem–Mahler–Lech theorem states that if a sequence of numbers is generated by a linear recurrence relation, then with finitely many exceptions the positions at which the sequence is zero form a regularly repeating pattern. More precisely, this set of positions can be decomposed into the union of a finite set and finitely many full arithmetic progressions.... Its proofs use p-adic analysis."